# How can I change the field param within the GET_LIST type in my dataprovider

Tags: react-admin

I am trying to retrieve a list of posts by their name rather than id. By default the dataProvider is setting the field param as 'id' within the sort const. How can I change this as my id's cannot be sorted as they're not ints?

```
case GET_LIST: {
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
        const { field, order } = params.sort;
        // above, the field param is always set as 'id'. How can I change it 
        const query = {
            sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
            range: JSON.stringify([
                (page - 1) * perPage,
                page * perPage - 1,
            ]),
            filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter),
        };
        options.headers.set('scopes','admin:read');
        const bearerToken = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
        url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The sort field can be configured in List:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#default-sort-field

```
<List sort={{ field: 'id', order: 'ASC' }} {...props}>
```

Comment: Thanks. I finally figured this out in the end but thanks for the response